# Some different objects as type in interface - Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have `User` interface in typescript project (Ionic 2), and I want that one of his variables to have 2 different options as a type.

Example of what I written:

```
export interface User {
    _id: string,
    usUnits: boolean,
    height?: UsHeightUnits | NotUsHeightUnits
};

interface UsHeightUnits {
    feets?: number,
    inches?: number
}

interface NotUsHeightUnits {
    centimeters?: number
}
```

This not cause me any errors, the errors comes in another file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../interfaces/user/user';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/profile-edit/profile-edit.html',
})
export class ProfileEditPage {
    public user: User;

    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
        // Here i have red error underline, under the "centimeters"
        this.user.height.centimeters = 4;
    }
}
```

There error is: `[ts] Property 'centimeters' does not exist on type 'UsHeightUnits | NotUsHeightUnits'.`

In other cases with `|` (or) it works fine, like this case that using strings and not object:

```
export interface User {
    _id: string,
    gender: 'male' | 'female'
};
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A union type has all the properties that both types have in common.

For a better understanding look here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html